# Issue running rake task on azure server (via cloud66)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, azure

So i've got a cloud66 server (azure) running my web app

I'm trying to get the rake task to run on my webserver to populate my database (it runs fine locally)

Heres the error log im getting back

```
W, [2016-07-29T23:22:55.602769 #44674] WARN -- : Failed creating logger for file /var/deploy/appname/web_head/releases/20160729211819/log/newrelic_agent.log, using standard out for logging.

W, [2016-07-29T23:22:55.610222 #44674] WARN -- : Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /var/deploy/appname/web_head/releases/20160729211819/log/newrelic_agent.log

D, [2016-07-29T23:22:55.610373 #44674] DEBUG -- : Debugging backtrace:

/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open-uri.rb:36:in `initialize'

/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open-uri.rb:36:in `open'

/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open-uri.rb:36:in `open'

/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/logger.rb:628:in `open_logfile'

/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/logger.rb:584:in `initialize'

/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/logger.rb:318:in `new'

/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/logger.rb:318:in `initialize'
```

Any ideas why this is failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the second line:

`Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /var/deploy/appname/web_head/releases/20160729211819/log/newrelic_agent.log`

To fix that you need to use a deploy hook to change the permissions on the folder.

Check out this community page for more information: http://community.cloud66.com/questions/rails-file-system-permissions

Also, you might find this page useful: http://community.cloud66.com/articles/permission-errors-during-deployment